# mySQL return index after insert

Tags: mysql

the way i have it is that I set up an insert command which works well
it add the entry to my DB ...since i want to insert other entries in other tables using the unique index that was obtained from the first insertion I do a query obtain the index then reuse it other insert...
though this works fine...I am sure there has to be a better way 
any suggestions?
thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the autoincrement index you can use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

or  `mysql_insert_id()` in PHP if you happen to use this language

Comment: what if multiple users are doing the same command at the same time....is there any risk that it will take the last Autoincrement from one of them and give it to the other?
example... 
user 1 does the insert 
user 2 does the insert
user 1 gets the autoincrement value
user 2 gets the auto increment value
is this scenario possible?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` is deprecated, but `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` works just fine