# mysql retrieve id after insert

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mySQL return index after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666277/mysql-return-index-after-insert)

Hy,

Is there a way that after inserting something in mysql database (`INSERT INTO table_name VALUES () ...`) to retrieve ID of that insert for further manipulation ?

The old way is to make the insert and then query a `SELECT` on the table name . But is there any way to do this in a single query ?

Thank you very much

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666277/mysql-return-index-after-insert   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667614/mysql-last-insert-id-and-found-rows   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266604/select-last-insert-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.mysql-insert-id.php).  Or directly in MySQL, call the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

```
// PHP
echo mysql_insert_id();

// PHP MySQLi
echo $mysqli->insert_id;

-- in MySQL
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: i`m using `mysqli` function ...

Comment: the problem is .. there can be lots of inserts in that moment ... i only want the ID from that specific insert .

Comment: @pufos if you need the insert immediately, before returning to PHP, you would need to use a stored procedure and call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySQL

Comment: thank you very much .. but let's assume that 3 users are doing inserts simultaneous .. the returned id will be correct ?

Comment: how can i do that ? that`s what i want `LAST_INSERT_ID` .. how to do that ?

Comment: @pufos, the last_insert_id() is stored on a per connection basis (see [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)), so different users won't interfere.

Comment: @pufos if 3 users do simultaneous inserts, the ID returned to PHP will still be correct because it is bound to the client connection.  from the docs -"The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients."_

Comment: O, thank you .. i read it now .. i understand . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you have a function called

```
 $lastId = mysql_insert_id();
```

for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php